# Working with subsites in SPO using PnP

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp-powershell, pnp

I'll preface this by saying my Powershell knowledge is fairly minimal and this is my first time trying to use PnP, so if there's something about my approach that seems off, please let me know. Currently have a new client with around 500 document libraries that are stored in a subsite (https://clientname.sharepoint.com/clients) that is under the default team site. The goal is to consolidate the files in these libraries within a single new library in a new site (https://clientname.sharepoint.com/sites/companyweb). Currently I'm having issues querying any of the libraries in the subsite via PnP. When I run `get-pnplist -identity "https://clientname.sharepoint.com/Clients/libraryname` or `get-pnplist -identity "https://clientname.sharepoint.com/Clients"`, I get no output. When I run this code while connected to the base site

```
$webs=Get-PnPSubWebs -Recurse
foreach($web in $webs)
{
write-host $web.Url -ForegroundColor Cyan
$sublists = Get-PnPList -web $web 
$sublists
}
```

It does output the expected library names and URLs as expected. Could there be something about the URL formatting that I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me.

```
Import-Module -Name SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline -Verbose

$cred= Get-Credential

#Config Variables
$SiteURL = "https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/SiteColl/"
 
#Connect to PnP Online - User this for Personal SPOnline Site
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteURL -Credentials $cred 

#Process the root web First
$rootWeb= Get-PnPWeb

$allLists=@()

#all list/library from the root
$listRoot=Get-PnPList -Web $rootWeb

$allLists=$listRoot

Write-host "Number of list in the root web: " $allLists.Count

#get all sub sites
$subWebs =Get-PnPSubWebs -Recurse


foreach($subweb in $subWebs)
{
   Connect-PnPOnline -Url $subweb.Url -Credentials $cred 

   $lists = Get-PnPList -Web $subweb

   $allLists+=$lists
}

Write-host "Number of list in All Webs: " $allLists.Count
```

Comment: using "https://clientname.sharepoint.com" for the SiteURL variable gets me a count of the lists/libraries in the root site, but it doesn't grab anything from the subsites. Running `Get-PnPSubwebs` and `Get-PnPSubWebs -Recurse` on their own while connected to the root site results in no output. Using "https://clientname.sharepoint.com/Clients" does get a count of the libraries though.

Comment: within foreach{}, in my script, I'm again connecting to the sub-site. Connect-PnPOnline -Url $subweb.Url -Credentials $cred  - Are you doing that?